Heat Trap Loop for Water Heater Outlet
I just installed a Rheem 50 Gallon Hybrid (Heat Pump) 240v water heater (XE50T10H45U0).  I put an 8" heat trap on the cold inlet, but not the hot water outlet.  I am noticing the hot water outlet pipe is consistently hot, so I can only assume the water is siphoning up and out.  The old water heater had top connections, so I re-piped it to drop down the side.
When I add a trap to the outlet, does the rise and fall of the loop need to be the same length?  Or if I bring the pipe to the water outlet above the pipe and drop back 6", will this work?  I am concerned if this longer rise versus drop would "force" hot water through the pipe.

